# Any way to embed contour over plot into fragments?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Is it possible to embed a contour over a plot into the actual fragments of the plot?  I would like to illustrate a contour integral over a function as for example a yellow line over a plot of the function.  Currently, I suppose we just superimpose the line over the plot.  Wouldn't it look nicer though if the fragment shader would actually color the affected fragments with a yellow line?  I suppose it's possible to check every fragment to see if the line is crossing it but I suppose that's too memory intensive.  Is this even possible?  Here is a link to my code you guys and others have helped me with.  Now, I'd like to plot a yellow contour over the branch surfaces and was wondering if the fragment shader could do this or do I have to plot them separately and superipose them?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dhdvgj0astxrah6/index.html?dl=0

Comment: Please [edit] and paste in whatever is at the dropbox link. (If it's an image, someone with high enough rep can edit it in for you once you add it properly.)

Comment: I don't understand.  The link I posted up there should run my html file that contains the code you guys have been helping me with; an interactive 3D webgl app.  What do I have to edit?

Comment: Perhaps though a more appropriate question is:  given a triangle primitive defined by 3 vertices and points p1 and p2 on the edges of 'this triangle that the contour traverses, design a fragment shader that will draw a yellow line from p1 to p2, shade-in the rest of the triangle with an appropriate color, and also include the mesh lines along it's perimeter.

Comment: I meant that the code you are asking about should be included in the body of the post instead of being behind a link. In general linking to something without including a copy of the content here is frowned upon, since links can change or go down. You want to include enough info that someone else can reproduce the issue without going to external sources (see also [mcve]).

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  The code above is perhaps not necessary;  just was a plot of the function I want to draw a contour over.  However, the main issue I thinks is what I stated above:  drawing a (straight) line contour across a triangle primitive from p1 to p2 on opposite edges.  I think it can be done although not immediately clear to me how to handle it.

Comment: The reason I ask this is that I independently generate the vertices in Mathematica and so could do the computations for p1 and p2 in Mathematica and could then possibly pass them to the shaders for each triangle.  Might be an interesting project to work on unless you guys tell me this is not possible.

Comment: This is a simple example of a line through a primitive using barycentric coordinates:   <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec4 vColor;
    varying vec3 vBC;

    void main(void) {
        if(vBC.y<0.2 && vBC.y>0.19){
            gl_FragColor=vec4(0,1,0,1);
        }
            else {
          gl_FragColor = vColor;
      }
    }
</script>

Comment: And here's an example of drawing a circle in a  triangle primitive so there are some plots we can draw inside a primitive using just the fragment shader.  I then wonder if there is any plot y=f(x) that I can draw inside a triangle using just the fragment shader?    void main(void) {
        if((pow(vBC.x,2.0)+pow(vBC.y,2.0)+pow(vBC.z,2.0))<0.5 && (pow(vBC.x,2.0)+pow(vBC.y,2.0)+pow(vBC.z,2.0))>0.49){
            gl_FragColor=vec4(0,1,0,1);
        }
            else {
          gl_FragColor = vColor;
      }
    }

Comment: post the code in your question where it can be formatted.

Comment: Ok sorry.  Whenever I hit enter key, my post gets posted before I can format my code.  For example to post my shader code to draw a straight line across a triangle primitive, I use:if(vBC.z>0.25 && vBC.z<0.255 ){
                gl_FragColor=vec4(0,1,0,1);
            }
            else {
                gl_FragColor = vColor;
            }  but I'm not able to format it nicely.  but while in the editor it is formatted.  How do I post nicely formatted code?